# How to replace the entire document in MongoDB using Ballerina MongoDB module?

Tags: ballerina

I want to know how to use `update` function in MongoDB module in Ballerina ([link](https://github.com/wso2-ballerina/module-mongodb)) to update/replace multiple documents entirely in MongoDB .

I have following documents in collection Employees.

```
{ "uid" : "1", "Name" : "Peter", "Team" : "A" }
{ "uid" : "2", "Name" : "Anne", "Team" : "B" }
{ "uid" : "3", "Name" : "John", "Team" : "C" }
{ "uid" : "4", "Name" : "Mary", "Team" : "D" }
```

I want to update above documents as below.

```
{ "uid" : "1", "Name" : "Peter Pan", "Team" : "A" }
{ "uid" : "2", "Name" : "Anne marie", "Team" : "A" }
{ "uid" : "3", "Name" : "John Cena", "Team" : "D" }
{ "uid" : "4", "Name" : "Mary Austin", "Team" : "D" }
```

Comment: Managed to do this using this [link](https://github.com/wso2-ballerina/module-mongodb/blob/master/component/src/main/ballerina/Module.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the example below.

```
json filter = { "age": "28" };
json document = { "$set": { "age": "27" } };
var result = conn->update("students", filter, document, true, false);
match result {
    int i => io:println("updated count: " + i);
    error e => io:println("update failed: " + e.message);
}
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/wso2-ballerina/module-mongodb/blob/master/component/src/main/ballerina/Module.md) for more information.